# Launching Chromedriver using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What options do I set for chromedriver so that the web server cannot tells the browser is manually launched or programming launched using Selenium?

Thanks,

Comment: If the browser was lunched manually Selenium can't interact with it, so there is no point for such feature. Maybe you should ask about the problem you are facing, it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Webserver you try to access has no way of knowing how the browser has been launched. It can only detect (or rather, guess) that it's an automated browser when said browser shows atypical behavior for a human (e.g. makes loads of requests per seconds, clicks 2 things with no delay whatsoever). Therefor it doesn't matter how you launch the browser - just how you use it.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? nothing is "guessing" anything. Selenium doesn't care how the browser was lunched, and it defiantly doesn't track how you use it.

Comment: @Guy of course selenium doesn't track anything. the way i understand the question, he was asking how to avoid being recognized as bot by a website.

Comment: MCO is correct. I try to avoid being recognized as a bot by a website. It disables the password login when I launch the chrome browser using selenium.